# My makefile is rebuilding .o even though .c is older

Tags: makefile

```
make "OBJECTS=`cat $1.objlist3.$temp`" "EXEC=$BINDIR/$1" "IOBJ=$objdir" "DIR=$curdir"  "CCFLAGS=$cflag" "INCLFILE=mk_include2.$temp" "LOPT=-lm $LOPT" -f../install/make/MAKEFILE_lx64


$(IOBJ)/%.o: $(DIR)/%.C
    ls -l $< $@
    $(CCC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $@ -o $<
```

the ls command confirms that .C is older than .o, yet it rebuilds.

Comment: Is that the real `makefile`?  You appear to be specifying the object file/target as the compiler input and the `.C` file as the compiler output -- `... -c $@ -o $<` ?

Comment: Use `make -d` or `make --trace` to see why make is deciding to rebuild the `.o`.  Most likely somewhere else in your makefile you have defined other prerequisites on the `.o` and these are causing the rebuild.  Obviously as G.M. says your compile line is also wrong but that doesn't explain why make is running it in the first place assuming your statement about relative timestamps is correct.